# Dynamically Adding TextBox using a Button within MVVM framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I keep climbing the steep WPF hill! So I want to create a UI that allows the user to dynamically add a text box.  To do this they would hit a button.

I've managed to create this using code behind but I want to move towards an MVVM structure so I don't have any code in the view. I've tried ICommand and ObservableCollection but I'm missing something and I don't know where.  Here is my simple example.

XAML: Very basic with one button that adds a row.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFpractice072514.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFpractice072514"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="mymy" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="ButtonUpdateArtist"
                Content="Add TextBox" Click="ButtonAddTexboxBlockExecute" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFpractice072514
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region members
        int count = 0;
        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonAddTexboxBlockExecute(Object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = new TextBox();
            t.Height = 20;
            t.Width = 20;
            t.Name = "button";

            RowDefinition rowDef1;
            rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
            mymy.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);

            ColumnDefinition colDef1;
            colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            mymy.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            ++count;

            mymy.Children.Add(t);

            Grid.SetColumn(t, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(t, count);

        }
    }
}
```

Questions: What code (XAML and C#) do I need to be able to move the method out of the code behind and into a viewmodel?

Can you use commands to dynamically add a textbox?

I'm assuming that the textboxes must be kept in a container which in this case is what grid is for. But if I'm using an MVVM do I need to contain the textboxes in a listview or some other container that uses ItemsSource?

Comment: This is not MVVM, which is probably why you are struggling.  In MVVM, I'd have a ViewModel with a public observable collection property of models bound to an ItemsControl.  I'd have a DataTemplate for the model type.  And I'd have an ICommand bound to the button.  When the button is clicked, the command fires in the view model, where I add a new model to the collection.  The UI would automatically add UI for the element using the DataTemplate.  That's why we do MVVM--it's easy.  What you're doing is windows forms.  If you want to create forms, do so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Follow these steps and you are done:

1. Use `ItemsControl` and bind it's `ItemsSource` to some collection (preferably ObservableCollection) in your ViewModel.
2. Define `ItemTemplate` for ItemsControl with TextBox in it.
3. Create an `ICommand` in ViewModel and bind it to button.
4. On command execute add item in the collection and you will see TextBox gets added automatically.

---

**XAML**:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add TextBox" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> SomeCollection { get; set; }
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CommandMethod);
    }

    private void CommandMethod(object parameter)
    {
        SomeCollection.Add("Some dummy string");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand**:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{    
    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }    

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

***Note*** - I assume you know how to plug View with your ViewModel by setting DataContext to make the binding magic to work.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, never would have thought of using a collection of  "dummy" models to create UI controls. One challenging part of learning WPF is just finding the properties, what objects can use them and what they are for.

Comment: Exactly WPF is more data driven whereas WinForms is more of UI driven technology.

Answer (score 3):

```
[link][1]

 class TestViewModel : BindableBase  
    {  
        private TestModel testModel;  

        public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }  
        public TestViewModel(StackPanel stkpnlDynamicControls)  
        {  
            testModel = new TestModel();  
            TestModel.stkPanel = stkpnlDynamicControls;  
            AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddMethod);  
        }  
        public TestModel TestModel  
        {  
            get { return testModel; }  
            set { SetProperty(ref testModel, value); }  
        }  
        private void AddMethod()  
        {  
            Label lblDynamic = new Label()  
            {  
                Content = "This is Dynamic Label"  
            };  
            TestModel.stkPanel.Children.Add(lblDynamic);  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: It is generally good practice to provide some explanation with your code.  You can edit your answer to add more information.