# What is the best way to add large number of text box in wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a WPF window which will a full screen (excluding task bar) and will contain a lots of text box.

I made this before in winforms. But in winforms , its easy to make and put all the elements inside a groupbox to make it look better but how to do this in WPF, because in WPF groupbox can contain single item.

I want  to make something like this:

[image]

Comment: I found the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960476/dynamically-adding-textbox-using-a-button-within-mvvm-framework) I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you list is a fixed length you put the text boxes inside another container such as a Grid, StackPanel or WrapPanel:

```
<GroupBox Header="Student Details">>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            ... as many RowDefinitions as you need
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            ... as many ColumnDefinitions as you need
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock .../>
                <TextBox .../>
                <TextBox .../>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock .../>
                <TextBox .../>
                <TextBox .../>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        ...
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

So, while the GroupBox can only contain one child, there's nothing stopping that child being another container type object that can contain all the elements you need.

I used a Grid here purely for illustrative purposes. The container you end up using will depend on how you need to layout your text boxes and labels. A grid gives you more control over the layout of the elements, but it's easier to add and remove elements from a stack panel - you don't have to add new row or column definitions.

However if your list is a variable length then you'd be better off creating a DataTemplate for the list item:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplate">
    <GroupBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock .../>
            <TextBox .../>
            <TextBox .../>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then using bindings to display the elements in a list:

```
<GroupBox Header=Student Details">
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding StudentList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             ....
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate/>
    </ListBox>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<GroupBox Header="Student Details">
   <StackPanel>
       <GroupBox>....</GroupBox>
       <GroupBox>....</GroupBox>
       <GroupBox>....</GroupBox>
   </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the size of boxes. I want to fit it in full window. Should I drag them or I mean.. how to size the boxes

Comment: GroupBox stretches by default. Inside GroupBox you may use Grid with columns for example

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960476/dynamically-adding-textbox-using-a-button-within-mvvm-framework)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UserControl to represent your Student Data with this xaml content:

**StudentControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.StudentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="300">
<GroupBox Margin="3">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Student 1" x:Name="StudentLabel" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="name" Margin="3"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="email" Margin="3"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

**StudentControl.xaml.cs (Code behind)**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class StudentControl : UserControl
    {
        public StudentControl(string labelText)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StudentLabel.Content = labelText;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your main window this is all markup you'll need:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <GroupBox Header="Student Details">
        <UniformGrid x:Name="StudentGrid" Columns="2" />
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

**And in the code behind file (MainWindow.xaml.cs):**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        StudentGrid.Children.Add(new StudentControl($"Student{i + 1}"));
}
```

Using an UniformGrid is great if you want to have the power of a grid layout but you're sure you want to distribute your space equally for all the user controls.

Hope this helps!