# Retrieve and save the Dynamic added control in WPF Xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[I have added the template based on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960476/dynamically-adding-textbox-using-a-button-within-mvvm-framework/24961352#24961352)

I have an **Add** button - when I click on it through Command I add it to a collection.

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource VieWModel}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="GH" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                            <tk:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" IsFilteringEnabled="True" Width="150" DisplayMemberPath="D"  IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GK}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SK, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </tk:RadComboBox>
                            <Label Content="HB" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                            <tk:RadComboBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" IsFilteringEnabled="True" Name="cb"  Width="350" IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="D"  ItemsSource="{Binding VR}" SelectedItem="{Binding VR1,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            </tk:RadComboBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel sample code:

```
     // Property for selected Item in combox1
            Public ValBase  SK{get;set;}

        //Property off combobox1 binding
        Public ValBase GK{get;set;}

        // Property ofor selected Item in combox2
        Public ValBase VR1{get; set;}

        //Property ofr combobox2 binding
        Public ValBase VR{get;set;}

        Public void AddButton(object obj)
        {
          var item =new collectionbase();
          Collection.Add(item)
        }
```

Whenever I click the **Add Button** this itemplate will be added.

**MyRequirement** :

1. When I Click **Add Button** for the first time ,template should get added
2. When I click **Add Button** for the second time Previous generated controls Must have contain the values,only then controls should be added to a collection and then new controls should be created
3. And I dont know how to save those values dynamically created in a collection

I am running out of Ideas how to achieve this can anyone help . **MVVM pattern**

Comment: you not supposted to set DataContext for DataTemplate when ItemsSource is given, change that accoring to MVVM and see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Selector Class.I have used CurrentInstance To Bind the Collection its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having Collection in MainViewModel and Command for add Model.

```
private Model _lastAdded;
public Model LastAdded
{
  get{return _lastAdded;}
  set{_lastAdded = value;}
}

private void AddCommand(object obj)
{
  if(_lastAdded != null && _lastAdded.SelectedValue != null)
  {
    var newItem = new Model();
    Collection.Add(newItem);
    _lastAdded = newItem;
   }
   else
   {
     //Show message
   }

}
```

Comment: Where to add LastAdded could you explain a bit and I hope it wont get added the First time

Comment: @SundarStalin the same class where you have Collection and AddCommand Methods.

Comment: I have Already Added it to MyCollection. When I add the Next time My combobox must have values only then It should get save.

Comment: see my edit.. you should use the property used in ComboBox selection in _lastAdded.SelectedValue. if you could , post model viewmodel codes

Comment: I have updated the DemoViewModel Code could you please update the complete solution  with correct variable names as in viewmodel